# Prime numbers from a listbox should appear to a textbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio, textbox, listbox, c#-3.0

I want to implement a code that take my inserted values from a listBox and show the as Prime numbers in textbox. 
Unfortunately , my textbox appear only the index of my prime number.

```
private void primnr()
    {
        int n = listBox1.Items.Count;

        for(int i=2; i<=n; i++)
        {
            bool prim = true;
            for (int j=2; j <i/2; j++)
            {
                if (i % j == 0)
                {
                    prim = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (prim)
                textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text + "Numerele prime:" +listBox1.Items[i].ToString() + Environment.NewLine ;
        }



    }
```

Comment: I test the code, but it doesn't trigger any exception. And you did not traversed the items in the listbox.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have numbers in your Combo items, you should access the item in that index position, in your case “i”

if (prim)
                textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text + "Numerele prime:" + listBox1.Items[i].ToString() + Environment.NewLine ;

Answer (score 0):

when I put this line 
`textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text + "Numerele prime:" + listBox1.Items[i] + Environment.NewLine ;`
 it shows this error :System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'InvalidArgument=Value of '2' is not valid for 'index'.
Parameter name: index'